# How to organize my data (for a restaurant search app)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a large list of restaurants in a txt file in the format:

Restaurant Name

Price Range ($$$)

Ranking (1-4 stars)

Location

Closest Subway Station

Type of Food

I am hoping to make a search script where I can search by one or more of the parameters, but I am not sure of the best way to organize the data. Should I make a class and add a dict of all (over 400) restaurants? Is there a more efficient way to do this? Is there a way for python to read my text file and do this automatically?

Comment: You should be using a database for this kind of stuff, not searching through a text file. It would make things a lot simpler, safer and more "neat"

Comment: 400 is not that much. You could simply store the data as JSON and load it into a `dict` with `json.loads`.

Comment: io is bad idea on serve (static file). comment #1 true